# Is it possible to assign different styles Gnuplot line on the graph, and the corresponding entry in the legend?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, legend

I have a data file(points.dat):

```
0.00    0.0
0.10    0.1
0.15    0.2
0.40    0.3
0.60    0.4
0.50    0.5
0.60    0.6
0.40    0.7
0.15    0.8
0.10    0.9
0.00    1.0
```

I run a gnuplot task (smoothing x(y) data with tmp file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal png size 600,400
set output "data.png"

set table '.tmp'
plot 'points.dat' using 2:1 smooth csplines
unset table

plot '.tmp' using 2:1 with lines, 'points.dat' with points pt 7
```

I have a two legend (key) entries:

[image]

but I want to merge the two:

[image]

I can draw a dummy **linespoints** outside the view window, but should be the right way.

---

@ Christoph comment

This is not "pure mathematics", there are some standard design graphs in technical documentation. The one who reads the report should be able to attach  ruler to the graph and see the approximate value of the parameter.

Now my choise "notitle" to both plot and dummy line with title:

```
plot 'tmp' using 2:1 with lines lt 6 notitle, \
     'points.dat' with points lt 6 notitle,   \
     1E999 lt 6 with linespoints title "My Cool Title"
```

[image]

(Sorry if stated confusing. This all google translate.))

Comment: I don't know how you could do that. Besides this I also think, that it doesn't make much sense since the two parts (interpolated lines and the points) have different origins and different meanings: the one maybe beeing the result of some calculations or measurements, the other a mere visual enhancement (?)

Comment: Added into question. And another thing: why the X(Y) graphics discriminated against with respect to Y(X)? Y(X) can have normal legends without shamanism.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I got you right: If you plot X(Y) or Y(X) doesn't matter at all. This comes into play only because you need the interpolation. An then you effectively have two data sets (the original one and the interpolated values), which you cannot plot with a single legend entry. So the 'dummy' plot is the way to go. BTW: you can also add this as your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I thought it was a common problem (x = f (y)). In engineering practice it is often necessary to show the distribution parameter on length/height with this form. And smoothing in such cases... Weird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now my choise "notitle" to both plot and dummy line with title:

```
plot 'tmp' using 2:1 with lines lt 6 notitle, \
     'points.dat' with points lt 6 notitle,   \
     1E999 lt 6 with linespoints title "My Cool Title"
```

[image]

Comment: What is 1E999? How can we use this for multiple data files in the same plot?